What type of statistical analysis is recommended for examining variations in risk and protective factors across male and female offending groups
I want to understand how risk and protective factors vary across separate male and female offending groups I have classified them into using group-based trajectory modelling (GBTM).
Using GBTM, I created two separate models. The first model contains five offending groups for males, with a sixth non-offending group. The second model contains five offending groups for females, with a sixth non-offending group.
Utilising these male and female groups, I want to see how they differ based on a set of risk and protective factors, such as parenthood status, marital status, mental health-related contact, and childhood maltreatment notification all of which are binary variables (1 = yes/ 0 = no).
I would appreciate any advice regarding how I could analyse these risk and protective factors across separate male and female offending groups using SPSS or R. For example, would you recommend multilevel modelling?
Thank you.
